# Name a function "delete" ... Delete is a reserved word

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
function messageService($http) {

  return { 

    get: function (query) {
      return $http.get("/api/v1/messages", { params: query });
    },

    delete: function (id) {
      return $http.delete("/api/v1/messages/" + id);
    }

  }

}
```

But delete is a javascript reserved function and when I call this function I get an error. Is there a way to avoid this without changing the delete name?

Comment: Why not use one of the many beautiful synonyms for delete like exterminate, destroy, pulverise, remove, nuke, blowintooblivion, alltheworldsastageandnowyoumustexitstageleft...

Comment: Please show the error. There should be no error for this in modern browsers.

Comment: @Craicerjack Because it is even more beatiful to have the same name as the http request ... lol ... Well, rename it is fine. I was just wondering if there was a way to keep it delete.

Comment: [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7rk6d1ha/) No error for me.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a string.

```
return {
  ...
  'delete': function(id) {
    return $http['delete']("/api/v1/messages/" + id);
  }
};
```

Note that you only need to make it a string in ES3 or lower. As of ES5, keywords can be used as property names.

For more information on using reserved words for properties, [see the MDN section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_word_usage) covering it.

> Reserved words actually only apply to Identifiers (vs. IdentifierNames) . As described in [es5.github.com/#A.1](http://es5.github.com/#A.1), these are all IdentifierNames which do not exclude ReservedWords.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to rename it, since you want the function to be more semantic anyway. If you end up having multiple things that you need to delete down the road, it's going to be much clearer to have the respective delete functions be named "deleteMsg", "deleteComment", etc., rather than just "delete".

Comment: The caller provides naming context in this case so `delete` is okay outside of it being a reserved keyword.  `destroy` is another common name for this operation.